# how to change WordPress Permalink Settings without using .htaccess file

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

actually my domain is on yahoo small business.
and yahoo small business is not supported .htaccess file
i am trying to remov index.html. i am using plugin but  it's not working
please help me to resolve this problem.

i want to removing index.php
/index.php/%postname%/(http://www.berylsystems.com/index.php/careers/)

like http://www.berylsystems.com/careers/

Answer (score 0):

You can try to copy the WordPress index.php with some modification in the html directory (or where your site goes online, thats may different on each provider). Copy the index.php from your WordPress root directory (no the theme index.php) and change the line:

`require('./your-directory-or-path-where-the-wordpress-is/wp-blog-header.php');`

Upload this in the html directory and change in your general settings the site url:  http://www.berylsystems.com/
While the WordPress URL stays the same.